# Android: Circular feedback on ImageButton

Tags: android, layout

How is it possible to set the background of an imagebutton kind of circular so that while pressing it the background shows a round background rather than a square one?

Round one (in actionbar):

[image: Round]

Square one (normal ImageButton):

[image: Square]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out!

[image]

Im using a selector called `button_background.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/circle_background" />
</selector>
```

And a round background drawable: circle_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#1f000000" />
</shape>
```

Now simply set it as a background for the ImageView:

```
<ImageButton
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/popup_edit"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:src="?attr/more" />
```

Et voilá :)